# Android Studio Lock File Error

Tags: android-studio

I'm currently working on an app for my business and Android Studio is preventing me from completing the simplest task, building the app.

Even making a brand new project and building it as the template still gives me the same error that's below.

```
Timeout waiting to lock file content cache (G:\My Drive\TEI\app2\.gradle\4.6\fileContent). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.

Owner PID: unknown

Our PID: 7396

Owner Operation: unknown

Our operation: 
Lock file: G:\My Drive\TEI\app2\.gradle\4.6\fileContent\fileContent.lock
```

I've even uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio, restarted my computer and deleted the .gradle folder so a brand new one had to be made

Does anyone know why it keeps doing this?

**Edit:** I don't have any other gradle instances using the file, as far as I'm aware

Comment: Is it write protected for any reason?

Comment: I don’t think so, how would I check that?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you've figured it out yet or not but all i did was open a terminal window and type: sudo chmod 777 -R .android and then type: sudo chmod 777 -R (Location of Android Studio) just in case and it worked for me